# Having a lot of trouble; illegal start of expression

Tags: java, netbeans

I'm very new to computer programming -- having literally started the course a little under 6 weeks ago -- and I'm having trouble currently with illegal starts of expressions in Netbeans.

The whole code goes as follows(since I don't even really know where to start):

```
public class Employees {
    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
        public class Employee

        //properties
        private String name;
        private String ID;
        private String salary;

        //constructor
        public Employee (String name, String address, String dob) {
            this.name = name;
            this.ID = ID;
            this.salary = salary;
        }

        //method to print details on employees
        public void printDetails() {
            System.out.println("Employee name: " +this.name);
            System.out.println("ID: "+ this.ID);
            System.out.println("Annual Salary: " + this.salary);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot declare a class (`public class Employee`) within a method declaration (`public static void main(String[] args) {`).

Best you move the declaration of the `class Employee` to its own file (Employee.java). If you don't want to move it to a different file, you can also move it to the *end* of the existing file. But you have to declare it `private` instead of `public` then.

Or you can make everything one class like this:

```
public class Employees {
    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Employees employee = new Employees("name", "address", "dob");
        employee.printDetails();
    }

    //properties
    private String name;
    private String ID;
    private String salary;

    //constructor
    public Employees (String name, String address, String dob) {
        this.name = name;
        this.ID = ID;
        this.salary = salary;
    }

    //method to print details on employees
    public void printDetails() {
        System.out.println("Employee name: " +this.name);
        System.out.println("ID: "+ this.ID);
        System.out.println("Annual Salary: " + this.salary);
    }
}
```

Comment: You can declare a class in the body of a method (local class). People hardly ever do it though.

Comment: @PaulBoddington Right … but let's not confuse the beginners with a feature probably never needed at all.